# Daemon Tools: English option suddenly disappeared

Tags: windows-8.1, language

I went to mount an ISO using Daemon tools and found suddenly all the options were in Cyrillic characters in the Windows Explorer menu.

I opened it up and the same was true of the main menu.  I fumbled around until I found the preferences and the language option and found it was set to Bulgarian.  Weird, but I figured I'd just change it back, until I noticed that English is no longer a choice!  I've changed it to Japanese, since, unlike Bulgarian, I can read it.  But considering English just suddenly disappeared I'm not sure how long this option will be available either.

Is this a known issue?

[image: English is missing from the options]